# How to use multiple post functions in node js epxress mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post

What I'm trying to do here is use the 2 functions but I don't know how to use both of them as they're both post functions with same name and I want to able to test using postman. These are in the same file

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const Joi = require('joi');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const _ = require('lodash');
const { users } = require('../models/user');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
```

this is the first post function

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
const { error } = validate(req.body);
if (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
}

let user = await users.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).send('Incorrect email or password.');
}

const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, 
user.password);
if (!validPassword) {
    return res.status(400).send('Incorrect email or password.');
}
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, 'PrivateKey');
res.header('x-auth-token', token).send(_.pick(user, ['_id', 'name', 
'email']));
});
```

this is the second post function

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
const { error } = validate(req.body);
if (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
}

let user = await users.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).send('Incorrect email or password.');
}

const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, 
user.password);
if (!validPassword) {
    return res.status(400).send('Incorrect email or password.');
}
});

function validate(req) {
const schema = {
    email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
    password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required()
};

return Joi.validate(req, schema);
}
```

and lastly the last line in the file

```
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 functions if I may ask?

Comment: i'd like for users to sign in and provide json web token if they are signed is admins for authorization to access specific functions and for regular users to sign in without providing a token.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 handlers for same REST endpoint with same METHOD. Why don't you change one to `router.post('/login')`